# Why does my multiline MySQL query not work in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

Hey guys dunno why this query doesn't work in node.js, works perfectly in mysql.

```
const query = `SELECT e.id, e.name, SUM(c.price) as totalSales FROM employees e. carmodels c, sales st WHERE e.id = st.employee_id AND c.id = stcarmodel_id GROUP BY e.id, e.name`;


app.get("/employees", (req, res) => {
  db.query(query, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What error is thrown when executed?

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near '. carmodels c, sales st WHERE e.id = st.employee_id AND c.id = stcarmodel_id GRO' at line 1"

Comment: As stated in the error, you must replace the dot with a comma after `employees e`

Comment: You have a spave `e. carmodels c,` in your query!

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable multiline queries.
Should be a parameter for mysql_connect function. Just check the lib you exported this function from.
By default this option is disabled to avoid sql injections.